# Http calls do not work in Angular 4 unit test - do not want to use mocks

Tags: angular

I am writing a unit test for a service.   The service makes an http call to a web service.

```
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
constructor(private http: Http) {}

this.http.get('/assets/data/xyz.json').subscribe(
   (response: Response) => this.parseXYZ(response)
);
```

Works perfectly fine in ng serve mode.  For the life of me I cannot get it to work in ng test mode.  When I look for ways all I find is experts trying to convert me over to use mocks of some sort.  Lots of tutorials for solutions with mocks involved.

I do not want to use mocks.  The customer gave me a huge json structure to work with.  To use mocks to duplicate that structure would require a huge amount of work. I am on a time crunch budget.   Is there any easy way to just get Http to work from unit tests?

Comment: No, there isn't.

Answer (score 1):

A so called mock object doesn't have to be complicated.

We can take good advantage of TypeScript's structural type system accomplish our goal quickly and with full type safety.

**my-service.ts**

```
import {Http} from '@angular/http';

export default class MyService {
  constructor(readonly http: Http) {}

  getXyz() {
    return this.http.get('/assets/data/xyz.json')
      // I think you probably meant map here, not subscribe
      .map(
      // Note: I removed the explicit type annotation on `response`.
      // Don't put type annotations on callback parameters. They hide bugs!
        response => this.parseXYZ(response)
      );
  }
}
```

Now for the test

**my-service.spec.ts**

```
import test from 'tape';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';

import MyService from './my-service';

// TODO: extract into a test helper module for reuse
async function createMockHttp() {
  // might need to configure your loader/bundler to handle json files (not hard)
  const data = await import('/assets/data/xyz.json');

  return {
    get(_: string) {
      return Observable.of({
        json: () => JSON.parse(data)
      });
    }
  } as Http;
}

test('`MyService.prototype.getXyz` something', async t => {
  const http = await createMockHttp();
  const myService = new MyService(http); // no injector, nothing fancy

  myService.getXyz().subscribe({
      next: xyzStuff => {
        t.deepEqual(xyzStuff, 'expectedValue');
      },
      error: error => t.fail(error),
      complete: () => t.end()
    });
});
```

By some definitions, that is a mock, but it is pretty much a basic stub object. It just pulls JSON in as a static file and only implements the methods we need. It doesn't use a mocking framework, it doesn't use Angular's nasty test libraries either. It just exercises your code directly.

Comment: I found a work around.   It was not simple or trivial.  I do not want to copy/paste it here because it is so crazy complicated that it will just cause more trouble than it is worth.   I do not care how fantastic mocks are.  I do not want to use them.   Hopefully in Angular 6 or 7 this issue will be resolved because it is annoying.

Comment: @JackT I'm not proposing that you use a complex mocking abstraction. I dislike such things and avoid them wherever possible. What I have here is simply called a mock for convention. It's just a dummy object that is used to test the service in isolation of the framework and of the network. This is ideal for unit testing. Did you try this code? Because it works by definition.

Comment: No, I found a way to run the unit test on the component as-is.

Comment: import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions, BaseRequestOptions, HttpModule, ConnectionBackend, XHRBackend } from '@angular/http';

Comment: beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpModule
      ],
      providers: [ ConnectionBackend,
        BaseRequestOptions,
        { provide: Router },
        XHRBackend,
        {
          provide: Http,
          useFactory: (backendInstance: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: BaseRequestOptions) => {
            return new Http(backendInstance, defaultOptions);
          },
          deps: [XHRBackend, BaseRequestOptions]
        }]
    });

Comment: Add this crazy garbage and then you can use this.http just like you want to.

Comment: @JackT I dislike that approach. It couples you to the testing framework. Also it means that you're testing angular infrastructure instead of or in addition to testing your own code. You're using the injector and all sorts of other services that are irrelevant to the behavior of the service. Creating a stub object that always returns the expected value allows you to test your service, also calling `this.http` making no modifications to the service and significantly reduces boilerplate. Approaches which use the angular testbed and injector to test services are fundamentally flawed.

Comment: This is so, so much simpler than using `TestBed`, and no less valid. Thanks!

Comment: Mocks do not test "your own code".  Mocks test a fake version of the something.   This fix of mine allows a developer to test the real version of that something.   At the end of the day, with mocks, you haven't really tested anything.   Does the real web service that is called with the component work or not?   Who knows, that's not what you tested.  You tested a mock version of it.   Cross your fingers that the mock version and the real version are the same.